# Unable to convert timestamp to date in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert a varchar field into date field using cast(date as date) but it is throwing an error as "Amazon Invalid operation: Error converting text to date".

I tried converting the same column using to_date(date,'Mon DD yyyy') function and it worked fine.

what could be causing this error in cast function and what can I do to rectify it?

I want to use cast specifically for this conversion.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cast(activity as date)
from akhil_date_conversion;
```

my activity field has values like:

```
Nov 24, 2002 9:02 AM
Jan 21, 2002 9:00 AM
Nov 17, 2002 9:00 AM
Nov 5, 2002 9:00 AM
Feb 17, 2002 10:00 AM
Jan 16, 2009 9:03 AM
Apr 20 2002 13:02 
May 11 2002 19:34 
Aug 11, 2002 12:00 PM
```

some have AM/PM and some do not!

Comment: Fix your data model so you are using proper data types!

Comment: Are those dates in a string? They are in a very bad format for data processing. Is there any chance you can receive those dates in a better format (eg `2002-08-11 19:34`)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a cluster parameter called datestyle that can be used to set the default date / time format for the cluster.  The default is ISO and what you have is closest to POSTGES.  This is used in outputting dates but also in interpreting them.  However, you don't have a consistent datestyle in your data (12 and 24 hour format changes) so I don't think this will work in your case.  You will need to write some SQL get your data into a single format before CAST will work by default.